# Failing at Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, factory

Failing over around `Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();` and I'm not sure why. I executed the stored proc with manual parameters declared and she worked just fine. Though, I'm not being given an error or anything to go off of, so I'm not sure whats wrong. I stick a break in the code on each line leading up to, and after the `Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();` line and it stops there, after I tell the IDE to continue it skips that line and the function ends.

For the record, my references are solid as well. I've cannibalized this code from another project I've done, so I'm likely just missing something silly. Regardless, here's the code:

```
public class PullDebtor
{
    public static DataTable ClientNumber(string strClientID)
    {

        DataSet dsDebtor = new DataSet();
        dsDebtor.Tables.Add("Debtors");
        DbCommand dbCommand = null;

        try
        {

            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

            string sqlCommand = "sp_PullClientID";
            DbCommand dbCommand1 = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlCommand);
            dbCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand1, "@ClientID", DbType.String, strClientID);

            db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand1);

            dsDebtor = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand1);
        }
        catch
        {
            return dsDebtor.Tables[0];
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return dsDebtor.Tables[0];

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you edited your `.config` sections? You need somethig like:

```
<section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

And you also need a config section pointing to the connection string you have defined in your connection strings section:

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="Connection String" />
```

Comment: I was in fact missing those important steps. However, after adding them in their respective locations we've gotten no further than before. Would seeing my web.config file help? I can troubleshoot when I have errors, however without errors I'm effectively useless.

Comment: <section
      name="dataConfiguration"
      type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data"  />


  </configSections>

Fixed it! I just had to stick the:

<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="Connection String" />

At the bottom before my config closed. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This solution did not work in my case. The configuration mentioned here is present in my windows service and yet the service stops at the exact line i.e. DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(). Shall I post exact same question ? Because the behavior is same in my case. Only difference is the EnterpriseLibrary version is 5.0.414.0

Answer (score 0):

You might know why had you not ignored the exception. `catch { ... }` is *rarely* a good idea (it's effectively never a good idea but I try to avoid always/never when giving recommendations).

Modify your code to something like this and see if you still need help:

```
try
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

    ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // this will dump to the output window in VS when running a Debug build.
    // Release logging will require something different
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);

    ...
}
```

Comment: I received 'The name 'Debug' does not exist in the current context' 

Is debug a reference I need to add?