# How to store DbType.Time from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I am not able to store a Time field into a table from asp.net, table column is of datatype `Time`.

I tried using

```
string TimeValue;
Database databaseObject = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
databaseObject.AddInParameter(command, "VIN_MONDAY_CLOSE_TM", DbType.Time, TimeValue);
```

It's showing the error

> ERROR [22007] [IBM] CLI0113E  SQLSTATE 22007: An invalid datetime
>   format was detected; that is, an invalid string representation or
>   value was specified. SQLSTATE=22007

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: TimeValue should be either DateTime or TimeSpan

Comment: As I see from your code - you are passing `string` as value of parameter to `AddInParameter`. I don't know what is your `Database` class exactly expects in this method - probably it should be `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` or maybe `string` - but in format that differs from yours.

Comment: `"VIN_MONDAY_CLOSE_TM"` what is the datatype.. can you show the database schema..?

Comment: One thing that you neglected to state is what DBMS you are using...

Comment: I think that it's probably `DB2` based on this ` [IBM]` `Jaques` did you read the error message

Comment: look at googling...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993628/failing-at-database-db-databasefactory-createdatabase

Comment: I tried passing the input as TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"). and DB datatype of the column is Time. and i am using DB2 database.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in datetime format and apply some format to it before adding to DB. 
for ex.  `DateTimeValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 0):

Time data based on a 24-hour clock.

Time value range is `00:00:00 through 23:59:59.9999999` with an accuracy of `100 nanoseconds`.